# Про­вести ча­стот­ный ана­лиз тек­ста: подсчет количества букв

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

На вход в про­грам­му по­да­ет­ся текст, со­сто­я­щий из про­пис­ных букв рус­ско­го и ан­глий­ско­го ал­фа­ви­та. между сло­ва­ми ста­вит­ся один про­бел, ввод тек­ста за­кан­чи­ва­ет­ся точ­кой. (Дру­гие сим­во­лы, от­лич­ные от "." и букв "А"..."Я" и "А"..."Z", на вход про­грам­мы не по­сту­па­ют.)
Тре­бу­ет­ся на­пи­сать про­грам­му, ко­то­рая будет про­во­дить ча­стот­ный ана­лиз тек­ста и по­сле­до­ва­тель­но вы­во­дить на экран толь­ко букву и число, рав­ное ко­ли­че­ству по­вто­ре­ний этой буквы. Вна­ча­ле не­об­хо­ди­мо вы­ве­сти дан­ные об ан­глий­ском, затем о рус­ском ал­фа­ви­те. Буквы, не встре­ча­ю­щи­е­ся в тек­сте ни разу, вы­во­дить­ся не долж­ны.
Помогите написать программу,этот код никак не хочет работать....

var

```
mas:array[1..255]of integer;
good:array[1..255]of boolean;
c:char;
i:integer;
begin
for i:=1 to 255 do begin
mas[i]:=0;
good[i]:=false;
end;
read (c);
while c<>'.' do begin
good[ord(c)]:=true;
mas[ord(c)]:=mas[ord(c)]+1;
read(c);
end;
for i:=1 to 255 do 
if (good[i]=true) then begin write(chr[i],' ',mas[i]);
writeln;
end;
readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

[[@kuvschinov-eugeny](/users/20628/kuvschinov-eugeny)](/users/20628/kuvschinov-eugeny)
Вы бы написали что конкретно не работает :)
Похоже что, вы забыли преобразовать число в строку при выводе результата. У вас же числа хранятся в `mas`, а не строки. Это вам не PHP, здесь строгая типизация. ;)

И ваш код можно сделать короче:

```
var
  mas: array [1..255] of Integer;
  c: AnsiChar;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 255 do
    mas[i] := 0;

  read(c);
  while c <> '.' do
  begin
    mas[ord(c)] := mas[ord(c)] + 1;
    read(c);
  end;

  for i := 1 to 255 do
    if (mas[i] > 0) then
    begin
      write(chr(i), ' ', IntToStr(mas[i]));
      writeln;
    end;

  readln;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо ввести строку символов, а вводится единичный символ (переменная c). В остальном код верный. Чтоб заработало меняем c:char на c:string